# JaCoCo stopped working after setting the log4j.configurationFactory system property

Tags: java, log4j, jacoco

JaCoCo stopped working after setting the `log4j.configurationFactory` system property.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

I've read about an error like that with JaCoCo and JDK 1.8, but it was already solved in JaCoCo 0.7.7.

The VM arguments are defined like following:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFactory=mytest.CustomConfigurationFactory
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-javaagent:/path/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:/TEMP/jacoco.exec,jmx=true
```

I'm using:

- JaCoCo 0.7.7
- Log4j 2.8.1
- JDK 1.8.0_102

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Downvoters, could you please explain reasons of downvote? For me (one of JaCoCo developers) this question looks perfectly valid and reveals a real problem in interactions between Logging, JMX and JaCoCo as explained in answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43902713/244993

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was answered in [JaCoCo users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/BFNE0YUrfiE/x1-9uT3KBgAJ) :

There seems to be a real problem in interactions between JaCoCo (up to the latest version that is 0.7.9 as of today), JMX and Logging when Log4j JDK Logging Adapter is used and JaCoCo agent registers JMX MBean. Deeper investigations would require some time, in the meantime

- either JaCoCo agent should be configured to not register JMX MBean, i.e. without `jxm=true` or equivalently with `jxm=false` (`-javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=jmx=false`), and should be noted that JMX is not the only option for remote connections to JaCoCo agent - [have a look](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) at `output=tcpserver` and `output=tcpclient`
- either Log4j JDK Logging Adapter shouldn't be used, i.e. without `‑Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`

## Update

And here is a ticket for a fix on JaCoCo side that explains what happens - https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/531